# How to display SUM of column in MySQLi and PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, sum

I have a MySQL database called 'test' with a table called 'week' which has two columns, one called 'address' and another called 'amount'.

I want to get the SUM of column 'amount' and display the result on the screen.

I promise I've looked all over the place for two days, but I am getting nowhere - I am very noob to PHP and MySQLi, so if anyone could point me to some example code to achieve this, I would be very grateful... thanks.

Comment: Can you please share the code you're trying with and the desired result you want?

Comment: Do you want a sum of every column or grouped by address? You should show us what you've tried also helps us get an idea of where you are.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Notice mysq_* is not safe to use (sql injection and stuff), but if you are not going to use user input, it might be OK.

```
<?php
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
    $result = mysql_query("select sum(amount) as total from test.week;", $link);
    if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) {
        echo "The sum is: " . $row["total"];
    })
    mysql_free_result($result);
    mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for everybody's help, I was making a mess of the connection and confused about some other functions. I am tryijng to use your code Ami, but I get - "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /var/www/html/info.php on line 7". As far as I can see there is nothing wrong, but I am a noob. I am using the code exactly as you posted it. Thanks again.

Comment: Ha! Got it! A missing ')'. Thanks everybody, it works!

Comment: @TravisBickle Note that `mysql_` functions are officially deprecated as of PHP 5.5 (released June 2013) and have been removed in PHP 7.0. It is recommended that you use PDO or MySQLi instead, that are much more powerful and safer to use, and you will avoid having to rework your code in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a simple sum of a colum of a table:

```
select sum(amount) from week
```